# Mostrar un valor en una caja en html

Tags: php, html

Tengo 2 archivo php, en el primero index.php es un formulario y el segundo salida.php donde asigno el valor a una variable pero no entiendo como mostrar ese valor otra vez en la caja creada en el formulario.

index.php

```
    <html>
        <head >
    </head>

    <body >
        <form method="post" action="salida.php"  >
            <input type="number"   name="Dato1" placeholder="Ingrese un valor" >
            <input type="submit"  value="Resolver">
        </form>
    </body>
    </html>
```

salida.php

```
    <?php

    include 'index.php';
    $a = $_POST['Dato1'];
    //No "echo $a" porque solo estaría mostrando en pantalla y no en la caja de texto creada en index.php
    ?>
```

Comment: Puedes colocar el dato que recibes en cualquier lugar, solo debes acompañarlo de las etiquetas de apertura y cierre de `PHP`, este es un pequeño ejemplo: `<div><?php echo $a;  ?></div>`

Comment: Eso mostraría el dato en cualquier lugar, pero con echo "<input type=text  value=$_POST[Dato1] >";  se crea una nueva caja y muestra el dato pero sigue sin ser la misma caja del index :(

Answer (score 2):

Haber, hay que partir desde el principio: los formularios en HTML son una serie de etiquetas que deben tener en cuenta, este se conforma con:

- Una etiqueta llamada `<form></form>` la cual tendrá varias propiedades, las cuales nos interesan dos: `method=""` y `action=""`. En una llevara el tipo de envió que será, si es `POST` o `GET`.

Te dejo unos links para que puedas leerlo y comprenderlo mejor:

1. [Mi primer formulario HTML por MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/Forms/Your_first_form)
2. [HTTP Methods GET and POST W3School](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp)

## Formularios en HTML

Comprendido esto, pasemos a como estructurar el archivo HTML. En tu ejemplo, veo que agregaste correctamente los datos en `method` y `action`, sin embargo a la hora de hacer el envió para que este formulario sea procesado por tu backend, no tienes un botón que sea tipo `submit`. Tomando en cuenta la doc. de MDN (dejada mas arriba) refactoricemos tu formulario:

```
<form method="get" action="salida.php"  >
  <input type="number" name="dato1" placeholder="Ingrese un valor" />
  <input type="submit" value="enviar" />
</form>
```

En este formulario le agregamos el `<ìnput type="submit"/>`, el cual fungirá como un botón de envió de datos. Además de cambiar el nombre que tenias antes en `name="Dato1"` por `name="dato1"`, esto con la finalidad de tener buenas practicas a la hora de desarrollar

## Usando PHP para trabajar del lado del servidor

Lo siguiente en la lista es crear el archivo `salida.php` el cual hará todo el ***backend*** o la ***transacción de tu formulario*** del lado del servidor. Si no comprendes este tema, te dejo otra lectura indispensable para ello:

1. [Cliente-Servidor en Wikipedia](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cliente-servidor)
2. Este video esta en ingles pero te ayuda a comprenderlo mejor [HTTP Crash Course](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iYM2zFP3Zn0)
3. En español te recomiendo este otro [Cliente-Servidor By Fazt Web](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=49zdlyLSwhQ)

Regresando el tema principal, veamos como trabajar con el archivo `salida.php`, según la [doc. de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/tutorial.forms.php). En tu archivo de salida deberías tener algo como esto:

```
<?php
echo "El numero ingresado es:" .$_POST['dato1'];
```

Si deseas agregar un campo de texto para recibir nombres, en tu formulario debes agregar otro `input` pero, ahora de tipo texto. Algo así:

`index.php`:

```
<form method="get" action="salida.php"  >
  <input type="number" name="dato1" placeholder="Ingrese un valor" />
  <input type="text" name="nombre" placeholder="Agrega un nombre" />
  <input type="submit" value="enviar" />
</form>
```

y en tu archivo `salida.php` lo agregas de igual manera:

```
<?php
echo "El numero ingresado es: " .$_POST['dato1'];
echo "El nombre ingresado es: " .$_POST['nombre];
```

Y de esa manera se mostraría los datos...

## A tener en cuenta

Como el ejemplo es sencillo, hemos pasado por algo varios temas, entre ellos:

1. Validaciones
2. Sanitizar formularios

Es por ello que te dejare algunos links para que puedas leer y comprender mejor lo que deseas llegar a hacer.

1. [Formularios y como tratarlos](https://www.php.net/manual/es/tutorial.forms.php)
2. [Formularios en PHP por Diego](https://diego.com.es/formularios-en-php) buen  articulo para conocer mas a fondo lo que te comente lineas arriba.
3. [Curos PHP por PildorasInformaticas](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLU8oAlHdN5BkinrODGXToK9oPAlnJxmW_) Curso gratuito, extenso y bien explicado de como trabajar con HTML, PHP y CSS.

Comment: Losiento olvide colocar esa parte, con respecto a tu respuesta necesito que se muestra dentro de la caja creada en el index.php, algo como un método set que se utiliza en java pero no se si es posible en php.

Answer (score 0):

Hola  lo que debes realizar es lo siguiente
debes de crear un boton tipo submit, tu action del formulario esta bien

Ahora en tu salida.php

solo debes de realizar lo siguiente

$a = $_POST['Dato1'];

echo $a

Comment: Esto que propones no cumple con lo solicitado en lo que el OP expone: *pero no entiendo como mostrar ese valor otra vez en la caja creada en el formulario.*

Comment: Si tienes 2 archivos diferentes lo dudo que lo puedas mostrar, a menos que trabajes con un solo archivo y utilices el metodo get, de retorno  y en tu caja solo debes añadir el valor value="$Dato1"

Comment: Creo que eso deberías agregarlo y explicarlo en tu aporte para que el autor de la pregunta tenga mejor contexto

Comment: Gracias por tu aporte Franco pero quería saber si era posible mostrar dentro de la caja creada en index.php al igual que el método set en java, si no, no tengo mas opción que trabajar en un mismo archivo.